# Renaming "java" directory to "kotlin" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

My android project is written 100% in Kotlin and I wanted to rename the java directory to kotlin to be consistent.  I added

```
sourceSets{
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

to gradle and renamed the directory.  All compiles and works fine.

The only issue is that when I am in the project tab, in "Android" view the directory is still named "java" (if I switch to the project view in the dropdown, I do see "kotlin" tho).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 22):

**Update (2)**

If you are using

**Android Studio Arctic Fox** version `2020.3.1 Beta 2`

and

**Gradle Plugin** version `7.0.0-beta02`

you are good to go and can just put put your code in `src/main/kotlin`.
Android Studio shows it as `kotlin` in the file tree. No need for adding the directory to the `sourceSet` as shown below.

[image: Android Studio Arctic Fox file tree]

---

**Update (1)**

Kotlin is finally coming to AndroidSourceSet. If you use the latest `Android Gradle Plugin` version `7.0 alpha`, you can use:

```kotlin
android.sourceSets.all {
    kotlin.srcDir("src/$name/kotlin")
}
```

---

This works fine in Android Studio `3.6.2` and should be the most versatile solution until `AndroidSourceSet` starts supporting Kotlin directly. Just add the following snippet at the end of your `app/build.gradle[.kts]`:

```kotlin
android.sourceSets.all {
    java.srcDir("src/$name/kotlin")
}
```

Comment: Works in Android Studio 4.0 RC1, it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @kroegerama does not work in Android Studio 4.0.1. I have added the code to the bottom of `build.gradle.kts` (app level) file, however `kotlin` folder showing as `java`.

Comment: Android Studio shows it as `java`, but the actual folder name can be `kotlin` (if you create a `kotlin` folder instead of a `java` folder in the filesystem). AS is not yet able  to show something other than `java`.

Answer (score 7):

Android Studio 3.6 has the same behavior. 
This is how I fixed it, in app/build.gradle:

```
// Register kotlin files
android.sourceSets {
     androidTest.java.srcDirs += "src/androidTest/kotlin"
     debug.java.srcDirs += "src/debug/kotlin"
     main.java.srcDirs += "src/main/kotlin"
     test.java.srcDirs += "src/test/kotlin"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

On Linux

In your modules gradle file ex: app.gradle

```
sourceSets{ 
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/' 
}
```

Comment: where are you adding this code to see this change because it is not working for me

Comment: it is not working for me either. Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: Are you using windows ? I'am on linux, for me it's working

Comment: This is the solution is I am using on the Mac and it works. Maybe you need to use backslashes with Windows.

Comment: It needs to be inside the `android { }` block

Answer (score 4):

I think this feature Android Studio. By default, the folder with the source code it is marked as "java". Even if you are in the "src/main" folder contains "kotlin" and "java".

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

After refactor renaming `java` to `kotlin`, syntax highlighting got broken, cannot CTRL + B to resources in source files.

So I opened an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140122569) in the issue tracker even mentioned the android view issue after renaming.

So for now I will keep the source directory name as it is.

---

Actually you just have to rename the `java` directory to `kotlin`, by right clicking on the `java` directory in `Project view` and select

```
Refactor > Rename
```

and type the new directory name as `kotlin`

**No need to add any code** to gradle file.

(Works on android studio 3.5, Linux Mint)

After refactoring on `Android view`, If it is a `Android app module` or `android library module` your source directories (java/kotlin) would not show up, but in regular `library module`s it will show up as `java`. In `Project view` all things look as expected.

Comment: That is not totally right. That is a solution which does not allow to access to the tests for any class.
That means that, if you make that refactor on Android Studio, everything looks fine, your app runs, but if you try to open a Test within a class (GoTo->Test), Android Studio is not gonna be able to access to the test

Comment: @FernandoPrieto I have not looked at the testing part, but as you can see in my updated section, it breaks the IDE functionality, that's why I opened an issue. Leave your a comment about the testing part there so they will look into that also.

Comment: I tested here with Refactory->Rename and :

It doesnt work all fine.


° Test and AndroidTest execution FAIL;

° Build APP OK; 

OBS: My Module renamed is 100% in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

even if it is supported in `android studio`, `kotlin` is still a plugin and v3.4 has the same behavior.

the solution:

```
sourceSets{ main.java.srcDirs += 'src\\main\\kotlin\\' }
```

in `settings.gradle` or `local.properties` works for me (windows)

Answer (score 0):

Simpler Solution
Go into Windows Explorer find your src directory
Inside you will find

```
androidTest/java
main/java
test/java
```

Rename those java directories to

```
androidTest/kotlin
main/kotlin
test/kotlin
```

**Testing**

Optionally remove the .idea directory

Re-load project from disk

Sync project with Gradle files

Rebuild Project and run Project