# Android - Java Package name not changes to Kotlin even though kotlin is used as a language

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am using kotlin as a programming in android application, even though am using kotlin as language my default application package shows as java.

[image]

But am not sure that this is the default behaviour, is it possible to change to kotlin ?

Comment: Yes, you can rename it to *kotlin* and then provide it as **sourceSet** in **build.gradle**.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467453/renaming-java-directory-to-kotlin-in-android-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming "java" directory to "kotlin" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467453/renaming-java-directory-to-kotlin-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can take any name as your *package name source*. All you'll have to do is just provide that name to **sourceSet** in Android Studio.

## How to do that?

Follow the steps:

1. Click on **java** package you want to refactor and then click *(shft+F6)*, popup opens and then rename it to **'kotlin'**.
2. Go to app level **build.gradle** file and then add code below in android block :

   ```
   android {
   ....
       sourceSets{
           main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
       }
   ....
   }
   ```

Now, sync the project and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using kts gradle system, then the code suggested by jeet might not work for you.

You can try with below piece of code in app level build.gradle.kts

```
android.sourceSets.all {
    java.srcDir("src/$name/kotlin")
}
```